# What is best practice in angular to re-use a function in several modules?

Tags: angularjs

I have a module config function, and I want to use it in several modules. I helped me this way, but I think, there might be a better way in angular.js?

```
(function() {
  angular.module("myApp", ["moduleA", "moduleB"]);
  angular.module("myApp").subModuleConfig = function(module) {
    return function() {
      console.log("Config Module " + module)
    }
  }
}());

(function() {
  angular.module("moduleA", [])
    .config([angular.module("myApp").subModuleConfig("A")]);
}());

(function() {
  angular.module("moduleB", [])
    .config([angular.module("myApp").subModuleConfig("B")]);
}());
```

Here is a plunkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/4LzLPgnF87WCbL3LeCIR?p=preview

Comment: use a factory or a service

Comment: I'm not sure, how I can use a service or factory function as a config fkt for another module - how would you inject the service in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a new module for configuration.

You can only inject providers and constants to config so instead of making `subModuleConfig` a factory you could make it a provider and just set `this.$get` to your configuration function (which might be even uglier though).

Using a factory you can set multiple different configurations into the same factory.

```
  (function() {
    angular.module("myApp", ["moduleA", "moduleB"]);

    angular.module("configModule", []).factory("subModuleConfig", function() {
      return function(module) {
        console.log("Config Module " + module)
      }
    });
  }());

  (function() {
    angular.module("moduleA", ["configModule"])
      .config(["subModuleConfigProvider", function(subModuleConfigProvider) {
        var subModuleConfig = subModuleConfigProvider.$get();
        return subModuleConfig("A");
      }]);
  }());

  (function() {
    angular.module("moduleB", ["configModule"])
      .config(["subModuleConfigProvider", function(subModuleConfigProvider) {
        var subModuleConfig = subModuleConfigProvider.$get();
        return subModuleConfig("B");
      }]);

  }());
```